# Three-layer parallax effect

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, animation

I want to make it lightweight (fastest, best performance) as it possible for browser, but I have no idea - I haven't huge knowledge about JavaScript.

That code run parallax effect on my web page. I have three parallax containers, which are different position background image. Script call on scroll event and when some container exist it's making it parallax-y. The first container (`'.parallax-top'`) exists always and hasn't any offset of image - it is always top-positioned. Second and third have offsets (1700 and 1400).

My page have a lot of content, scripts, images and I want to make all of them lightweight as it is possible.

```
if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
    (function() {
        var parallaxTop = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax-top");
        if ($(".parallax-center").length) {
            var parallaxCenter = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax-center");
            var centerPosition = $(".parallax-center").position().top;
        }

        if ($(".parallax-bottom").length) {
            var parallaxBottom = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax-bottom");
            var bottomPosition = $(".parallax-bottom").position().top;
        }
        var speed = 0.4;
        window.onscroll = function() {

            [].slice.call(parallaxTop).forEach(function(el, i) {
                var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
                    elBackgrounPos = "center " + "-" + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";
                el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;
            });
            if ($(".parallax-center").length)
                [].slice.call(parallaxCenter).forEach(function(el, i) {
                    var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
                        elBackgrounPos = "center " + "" + ((windowYOffset - centerPosition) * speed + 1700) + "px";
                    el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;
                });
            if ($(".parallax-bottom").length)
                [].slice.call(parallaxBottom).forEach(function(el, i) {
                    var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
                        elBackgrounPos = "center " + "" + ((windowYOffset - bottomPosition) * speed + 1400) + "px";
                    el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;
                });
        };
    })();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, why are you using `querySelectorAll` when you use jQuery? Use jQuery's `$(SELECTOR_STRING_HERE)` instead.
- I believe you're using `querySelectorAll` because you're trying to use `forEach`. Unfortunately, `forEach` is slower than your regular loops. Internally, jQuery uses a `for-in` and `for` in their `each` implementation, which may be faster than `forEach`.
- Again, you use jQuery but you use `window.onscroll`. Use jQuery's event mechanism instead.

I believe you're trying to go native in your code assuming things would go faster. But you're trying to solve the wrong problem. The real problem is the `scroll` event. Just scrolling a notch of your mouse wheel will fire the scroll event a dozen times, more or less. Now in your handler, you have this:

```
[].slice.call(parallaxTop)
```

What this code does is:

1. Create an array (the `[]` part)
2. Create a copy of that array (the call to `slice`)
3. It appears 3 times in your handler

That means if the handler fired a dozen times, this means you created 6 arrays per fire. A dozen would mean 72 arrays. Note that when the garbage collector runs, it "stops the world" (stops everything, scripting and rendering), causing freezes every now and then.

Additionally, `forEach` is synchronous. Nothing else happens when it's running, and doing something that takes too long inside each iteration will hurt performance. That and the GC, you'll eventually leave a very small gap for rendering.

What I suggest is to move your logic in a separate function and throttle your handler. That is, you only call your logic once the scroll has fired for at least some time, or at least a number of times. Only then will you update your element positions.

Now you'd wonder if you scrolled for a second and you scrolled 500px, wouldn't the background just jump? Yes, but that's where CSS transitions come in. You transition the `background-position` property so that the background will slide (depending on the easing function) to the updated position instead of jumping to it.

But, if I were you, I'd save my time and effort and instead, [use a plugin for parallax effects](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/).

Comment: Thank You very much for advices! That is, what I need. I will think about it. Also linked plugin is amazing! Maybe I will use it in next project.

Comment: Hm, could You tell or show how to do that with `background-position`transition with easing, please? CSS transitions probably might be the best solution.